# "InternalsVisibleTo" attribute not exposing method marked as "internal"

Tags: c#-4.0, windows

In below snippet, the method **GoodBye** is marked as **internal** by default. I have added below line in AssemblyInfo.cs file to make this method available in all other assembly.

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("ConsoleApplication2")]
```

Still the class not expsoses the GoodBy method to outside. Can anyone please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance!

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) { }
        public void SayHi() { }
        internal void GoodBye() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used the fully qualified name of the assembly?

Comment: @Lukazoid No, I did not signed with a stong name key.

Comment: What are the names of the two assemblies, `ConsoleApplication2` contains your internal method, what is the external assembly which is trying to consume these internal methods called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` must be provided with the name of the assembly you wish to be able to view your internal methods.

In your example, you appear to be saying: The internal methods of `ConsoleApplication2` are visible to `ConsoleApplication2`.

What you instead want to be saying is The internal methods of `ConsoleApplication2` are visible to `SomeOtherLib`, which you would do like so:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("SomeOtherLib")]
```